# recaptcha plugin for .net shows error on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, recaptcha

I am trying to set up a captcha in MVC; I am following the steps in [this article](http://dailysoftwarebugs.blogspot.com/2013/01/setting-up-recaptcha-in-mvc4-application.html) to the letter. While testing I found that the application gets an "Unable to connect to remote server" error. Clicking submit on a form with the captcha field empty works fine, it goes through the controller method with no problems. It's only when there's stuff typed on the captcha field that an error comes up regardless of if the verification is not correct. Also, VS 2013 says that a class from the Recaptcha library - RecaptchaControlMvc.cs -is not found.

Comment: Did you do this step: Now use NuGet and install the reCAPTCHA plugin for .NET ?

Comment: Yes, I installed [these](https://www.nuget.org/packages/recaptcha/) two [NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCaptchaMvcExtensions).